# Trying to list Azure Virtual Network and export to CSV using Powershell

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-virtual-network, subnet

I am trying to create a script that can list all the Azure virtual networks and export it into Csv using Powershell.

```
$day = Get-Date -Format " MMM-yyyy"
$path = "C:\Users\admin-vishal.singh\Desktop\Test\Report\"+ "$day-Vnet-Report.csv"
foreach ($Sub in $Subs) { 
    Select-AzSubscription -SubscriptionName $Sub.Name | Out-Null
    $resource_grps = Get-AzResourceGroup

    foreach ($resource_grp in $resource_grps) {

        $networks = Get-AzVirtualNetwork 
        foreach ($vnet in $networks)
        {
        $null = Get-AzVirtualNetwork |Select-Object SubscriptionName,ResourceGroupName,Name,AddressSpace,Subnets,SubnetAddressSpace,RouteTable | Export-CSV -Path $path -NoTypeInformation -Encoding ASCII  -Append
        
        }
    }
}
```

I am not able to retrieve data in the right format & getting errors when retrieving data.
Below is snippet of data
[image]

Lots of values I am not able to retrieve like Subnet AddressSpace, Route Tables and Routes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building on what Jim Xu provided, you don't need to have a separate loop for each ResourceGroup. Get-AzVirtualNetwork will return all virtual networks for the entire subscription. Also, you'll need an expression for the SubscriptionName in the Select-Object, so the code would look like this:

```
foreach ($Sub in $Subs) { 
    Select-AzSubscription -SubscriptionName $Sub.Name | Out-Null
    Get-AzVirtualNetwork | 
        Select-Object  `
            @{label='SubscriptionName'; expression={$Sub.Name}}, `
            ResourceGroupName, `
            Name, `
            @{label='AddressSpace'; expression={$_.AddressSpace.AddressPrefixes}}, `
            @{label='SubnetName'; expression={$_.Subnets.Name}}, `
            @{label='SubnetAddressSpace'; expression={$_.Subnets.AddressPrefix}} |
        Export-CSV -Path $path -NoTypeInformation -Encoding ASCII  -Append
}
```

Comment: It is working but unable to retrive the Address Space for Vnet, That coloum gives blank output else it works fine.

Comment: Sorry it should have been expression={$_.AddressSpace.AddressPrefixes} (instead of AddressPrefix). I've updated the code.

Answer (score 1):

When we call `export-csv` command, the property values are converted to strings using the ToString() method. But the result of `Get-AzVirtualNetwork` are object, we cannot directly convert the value to string. For more details, please refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/export-csv?view=powershell-7.1#notes) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.commands.network.models.psvirtualnetwork?view=azurerm-ps)

So regarding the issue, I suggest you create a custom object with the information you need then save it into csv.

For exmaple

```
$vents =Get-AzVirtualNetwork| 
  Select-Object  SubscriptionName,ResourceGroupName,Name, @{
   label='AddressSpace'
   expression={$_.AddressSpace.AddressPrefix}}, @{
     label='SubnetName'
     expression={$_.Subnets.Name}
   }, @{
      label='SubnetAddressSpace'
     expression={$_.Subnets.AddressPrefix}
   }
 $vents | convertto-csv
```

[image]

Comment: It works, Thanks.
How I can also add the route table details.
I tried to call the object for route table but did not got output